# Concatenar String no Firebird

Tags: firebird, sintaxe

Como se concatena String no Firebird?

estou tentando assim:

```
select ("00"||"01") AS TESTE  from tabela
```

Já tentei com parenteses, sem parenteses, com nome da coluna, sem o nome da coluna... simplesmente não vai...

esta dando o seguinte erro:

> can't format message 13:794 -- message file c:\Program Files\Borland\InterBase/interbase.msg not found.
>   Dynamic SQL Error.
>   SQL error code = -206.
>   Column unknown.
>   00.
>   unknown ISC error 336397208.

Comment: É assim, pena que não tem como eu testar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troquei as aspas duplas "" por aspas simples '' e funcionou, não sei se é o programa que uso *IB expert* ou se é o Firebird, só sei que assim resolveu.

Answer (score 3):

exatamente o padrão de interpretação de uma string no IB é utilizando aspas simples mesmo você está correto na conclusão.

Att.